# Using nested mapping in automapper

Tags: c#, asp.net, automapper

I am trying to configure Automapper so that it automatically maps an object to another object type when mapping the object it's contained in.

I have an event entity:

```
 public class Event {

   public int Id { get; set; }     

   public String Name { get; set; }

   public AppUser Creator { get; set; }

   public Photo MainPhoto { get; set; }

}
```

This is the AppUser Entity:

```
public class AppUser
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string UserName { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
```

This is the Photo entity:

```
public class Photo
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        
        public string publicId { get; set; }

        public string Url { get; set; }


    }
```

I have this CreateEvent method in one of my controllers which handles the creation of the event and adds it to my sql lite database:

```
[HttpPost]

   public async Task<ActionResult<EventDto>> CreateEvent(EventDto newEvent)
    {
    
     var createdEvent = _mapper.Map<EventDto, Event>(newEvent);
    
     await _eventsRepository.CreateEvent(createdEvent);
    
     return newEvent;
    
    }
```

This is the EventDto:

```
 public class EventDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public PhotoDto MainPhoto { get; set; }

        public MemberDto Creator { get; set; }
        
    }
```

This is the Automapper config class I have:

```
public class AutoMapperProfile : Profile
    {
        public AutoMapperProfile() {
            CreateMap<AppUser, MemberDto>();

            CreateMap<MemberDto, AppUser>();

            CreateMap<Photo, PhotoDto>();

            CreateMap<PhotoDto, Photo>();

            CreateMap<Event, EventDto>();

            CreateMap<EventDto, Event>();
            
        }
    }
```

So when the EventDto is converted to the Event entity here (see above in the CreateEvent method) :

```
var createdEvent = _mapper.Map<EventDto, Event>(newEvent);
```

I want the 'PhotoDto' to automatically convert into a 'Photo' object and the 'memberDto' to automatically convert into an 'AppUser'.

Is there anyway to achieve this with Automapper?

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Nested-mappings.html

Comment: Thanks for providing the link. According to the link, my above code should work. I am receiving a 500 server error when using the above code but when I manually map the above (without using Automapper), no error is being received.

Comment: Look at `exception.ToString()`.

Comment: Thanks. It seems that entity framework is not automatically incrementing the id on the event entity when a new event is created. Every event that is created is being created with a 0 as the id. I know this is a different question to my OP but any ideas why this would be happening?

Comment: I think you should ask a new question with _all_ the relevant info. I was only interested in the AM part.